# How to assign random numbers (0-10) to strings stored in a linkedlist

Tags: java, string, random, linked-list

I am as the title states I am having trouble assigning random number values to string stored in a `linkedlist`. Here is my `linkedlist`:

```
List<String> genres = new LinkedList<>(); 

         attributes.add("Action");
         attributes.add("Comedy");
         attributes.add("Documentary"); 
         attributes.add("Romance");
         attributes.add("Drama");
```

I came up with something like this, but I realised it is for an array and not `linkedlist`:

```
Random ran = new Random(); 

String genres_ran = genres[ran.nextInt(genres.length)];
```

I greatly appreciate any help, many thanks!

Comment: Use genres.get(ran.nextInt(genres.size()))

Comment: Access via an index to a `LinkedList` is actually not the greatest idea, because the runtime is `O(n)`. Depending in your usecase, you may be much better of using an `ArrayList`.

Comment: please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *assign* random numbers to strings, use a Map data structure.

However, looking at your attempt, it seems you want a random member from the List. Do this:

```
String randomGenre = genres.get(new Random().nextInt(genres.size()));
```

Comment: Thank you Bijay, I'll give it a try.